# Pop-up Div to appear on hover of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a website where i want to display a div on hover of a button. Currently i am able to do this but it's not the desired effect. I have created a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/marsone/quADx/2/) in jsfiddle to show what i have achieved and i will paste my HTML, jQuery and only the CSS which is pertaining to this question.

HTML

```
<div class="cart-btn" ><a href="#">CART</a>    
</div>
<div class="minicart" >
   Items : 5
   Total : $250
    <a href="#" style="color:#fff;">VIEW CART</a>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".cart-btn").hover(

    function () {
        $(".minicart").show(100);
    }, function () {
        $(".minicart").hide(2000);
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.minicart {
    width:164px;
    display: none;
    background-color:#0A3151;
    opacity:0.8;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:9999;
    margin-left:450px;
    margin-top:30px;
}
```

***ISSUE:*** The desired effect i want is, "The div should slide from under the button" and dissapear in the same manner".

However my main concern is that the div should remain focused even when i hover over it. Currently it disappears as soon as i take my mouse away from the button. The div once displayed should remain displayed unless the user takes the mouse away either from the div or button.

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/quADx/3/

Comment: Yes. Exactly. But my main concern is the div should not hide if the user moves his mouse over the div.

Comment: Here's an update for @BeNdErR 's fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/quADx/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to note, when using absolute positioning use top instead of margin-top and so on.

Second to avoid the popup folding up when you leave the button use the following selector:

```
$(".cart-btn, .minicart").hover(
    function () {
        $(".minicart").slideDown(100);
    }, function () {
        $(".minicart").slideUp(2000);
});
```

Use slideDown and slideUp as BeNdErR sugested, here's an updated version of his [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/quADx/19/)

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap both button and div in another div. The use this div for hover-event.

```
<div id="cbutt">
    <div class="cart-btn" ><a href="#">CART</a>
    </div>
    <div class="minicart">Items : 5 Total : $250 <a href="#" style="color:#fff;">VIEW CART</a>
    </div>
</div>  


$(document).ready(function () {
$("#cbutt").hover(

function () {
    $(".minicart").show(100);
}, function () {
    $(".minicart").hide(2000);
});
```

})

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ncj2E/

Hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: I cannot change the HTML